# Java Program Using Split to Validate Input. Simplifying, But Keeping Things Fuctional

Tags: java, arrays, string, input, split

Any help would be appreciated.

I am not trying to list the operators, ( I know that it would work that way) i want to know if i can put them in a bundle as i attempted in my code below (it did not work, anyone knows why? how to fix it?):
}

```
        double num1 = Double.parseDouble(token[0]);
        double num2 = Double.parseDouble(token[2]);
        double answer;
        String function = "[+\\-*/]+"; //this
        String[] token = input.split(function);//and this
        String operator = token[1];//this is the operator

        if (operator.equals(function)){
            for (int i = 0; i<length; i++) {

            }
            System.out.println("Operation is " + token[1] + ", numbers are " + token[0] + " and " + token[2]);
            }
        else {

            System.out.println("Your entry of "+ input + " is invalid");
        }


        }
```

Comment: What does _it did not work_ mean? What is your input and output, and your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you should split .you can't access `token[0]` before `declare` tokens

```
String function = "[+\\-*/]+"; //this
String[] token = input.split(function );//and this
```

then use array[index]

```
double num1 = Double.parseDouble(token[0]);
double num2 = Double.parseDouble(token[2]);
```

edit....

you should use .`matches` instead .`equals` because .equals looking for entire String not regular expression

complete code

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("enter your operation");
String input = scan.next();
String function = "[+\\-*/]+"; //this

String[] token = input.split(function);//and this

double num1 = Double.parseDouble(token[0]);

double num2 = Double.parseDouble(token[1]);

double answer;
String operator = input.toCharArray()[token[0].length()]+"";
if (operator.matches(function) && (token[0]+token[1]+operator).length()==input.length()) {

    System.out.println("Operation is " + operator+ ", numbers are " + token[0] + " and " + token[1]);
} else {

    System.out.println("Your entry of " + input + " is invalid");
}
```

output>>

```
for input "2+3"   >  Operation is +, numbers are 2 and 3
for input "24+45" > Operation is +, numbers are 24 and 45
for input "2++4"  > Your entry of 2++4 is invalid
```

Comment: getlost, i see what you are saying, but i did not understand the concept of using an array index, can you please elaborate on it?

Comment: @Integral sure.but first tell me what are u trying to do with your code?

Comment: I am trying to validate the user input of + - / or *. I wolud declare them in a println saying if the input of length [0], [1]the ones bunched in the split, and [2] the other number in the expression.

Comment: @Integral i think that's you want.check my updated one

Comment: oh man, please bare with me, getlost because i'm getting lost. I am placing in input from java scanner. I even tried placing what you have given me, but it is saying that num1 and num2 are invalid. How do I assure that num1 and num2 would be recoginzed at there place with bundling the operations. Also, bundling them would mean that the numbers input would change from 0 and 2 to 0 and 1? how is that if i am using length and the operator is 1 and the first number is 0 and the second number is 2 in length position when taking token " " in perspective.

Comment: @Integral if your input 2+3 when what is the output you expect?and if user input 2++3 then what is the output u expect?plz clarify and i updated my answer with scanner check it

Comment: Okay if do input to console of 2 + 7, i want the output of " operator is: +, and the numbers are 2 and 7", and i want to use it to then answer, but if i get this, ill get that.

Comment: @Integral my answer is exsactly gives you the "operator is: + and the numbers are 2 and 7" .didn't u run it?? i added scanner too

Comment: @Integral above code stating from scanner is exact code.see the output i have add to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

the code may be like this

```
double answer;
String function = "[+\\-*/]+"; //this
String[] token = input.split(function);//and this
double num1 = Double.parseDouble(token[0]);
double num2 = Double.parseDouble(token[1]);
String operator = input.substring(token[0].length,token[0].length+1)//this is the operator

if (token.length > 1){
    System.out.println("Operation is " + token[1] + ", numbers are " + token[0] + " and " + token[2]);
    }
else {

    System.out.println("Your entry of "+ input + " is invalid");
}
}
```

Comment: That did not work, java is telling me that i need to change the name of token in string [] token. It is declared ealrier as private static void splitEntry(String input) {
   String token [] = input.split(" "); 
   int length = token.length;

Comment: rename the String[] token to new name, the string split function will not return the splitor string ,if you want to get the matcher, you had better use the java.util.regex.Matcher or  Pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Access token after splitting input

```
double num1 = Double.parseDouble(token[0]);
double num2 = Double.parseDouble(token[2]);
```

And

```
String operator = token[1];//this is the operator
```

wont work because delimiter wont be there in the String array after splitting.