# Java geting operators from within a split for function purpose

Tags: java, if-statement, split, match

Okay... I think I might have gone over my head with trying to simplify this code. I place operators such as `( *, +, /, -)` in a split. Know i want to call them individually to do their perspective task in a `if (operators.equals.(+)){`
`return num1 + num2. }`
then for *, -, / perspectively

how can i do that correctly having using math in my earlier code:

```
String function = "[+\\-*/]+"; //this

String[] token = input.split(function);//and this

double num1 = Double.parseDouble(token[0]);

double num2 = Double.parseDouble(token[1]);

double answer;

String operator = input.toCharArray()[token[0].length()]+"";

if (operator.matches(function) && (token[0]+token[1]+operator).length()==input.length()) {

System.out.println("Operation is " + operator+ ", numbers are " + token[0] + " and " + token[1]);
} else {

      System.out.println("Your entry of " + input + " is invalid");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what's your question? I'm having trouble parsing "how can i do that correctly having using math in my earlier code"?

Comment: I did not mean to write math, I meant, how can I place if and if else statements thought to give the return of the operator with the two numbers. Example: num1 is 5 operator is * and num2 is 1, so answer is 5. How would I do that is my operators are all bundled in the index?

Comment: So you're trying to build the parser part of a calculator? I'm sorry, but there's no (easy) way around mapping "if you encounter this symbol, do this" (what you call "call them individually"). What you can do is map a `token` to a method name and use java reflection to call the method. But that's about it.

Comment: Also, I'm at a loss to what's different from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500578/java-program-using-split-to-validate-input-simplifying-but-keeping-things-fuct)?

Comment: @mali, I actually wanted to advance my written code that was fully functional to a code with much less lines, so I decided to eliminate the rubbish of calling each operator separately and  now I now have a problem making sure that the code is compatibile. Know they are bundled, how do I make if the operator chosen is + make a call to return num1 + num2. Get it?

Answer (score 2):

### You don't.

[`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) only returns the parts of the `String` that were not matched. If you want to know the matched code, you need to use a more sophisticated regular expression, i.e. the [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) classes, or write your own `String` tokenization class yourself.

In this example `Token` is a class you make yourself):

```
public List<Token> generateTokenList(String input) {
    List<Token> = new LinkedList<>();

    for(char c : input.toCharArray()) {
        if(Character.isDigit(c)) {
           // handle digit case
        } else if (c == '+') {
           // handle plus
        } else if (c == '-') {
           // handle minus
        } else {
           /* you get the idea */
        }
    }
}
```

There are libraries that do this for you, such as [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) but this sounds like a school assignment so you probably have to do this the hard way.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `if` body to something like

```
if (operator.matches(function) && 
        (token[0] + token[1] + operator).length() == input.length()) 
{
    double result = 0;
    if (operator.equals("+")) {
        result = num1 + num2;
    } else if (operator.equals("-")) {
        result = num1 - num2;
    } else if (operator.equals("*")) {
        result = num1 * num2;
    } else if (operator.equals("/")) {
        result = num1 / num2;
    }
    System.out.printf("%.2f %s %.2f = %.2f%n", num1, operator, num2,
            result);
}
```

And your code works as expected.

Comment: write on point, but can you tell me what is this mubojumbo? printf("%.2f %s %.2f = %.2f%n

Comment: I suggest you read up on [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax). "%.2f" is a floating-point number with two digits after the decimal point, "%s" is a `String` and "%n" is new-line. So it prints something like "#.## <operator> #.## = #.##\n" where the `#`(s) (and <operator>) are replaced by the values.